# Python 3, change range in for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range

I am trying to make a for double for-loop where the inner loop has the same range as the i in the outer loop. This would basically be what I want, but (obviously) it doesn't work:

```
num = 1
totalrow = range(5)
rownum = range(num)

for i in totalrow:
    for x in rownum:
        do stuff
        num = num + 1
        print (stuff)
```

So what I would like to happen, is to get 5 loops, where the first loop gives 1 result, second loop gives 2 results, etc. I don't know if it's needed for more clarification, but I am trying to create the drinking game ride the bus in python and I need this loop for the pyramid round. Is it possible like this or do need to find a different way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The result I was looking for was achieved by using this code:

```
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(i):
            card = random.choice(deck)
            deck.remove(card)
            print (card)
```

This gives me 15 cards from the deck of cards I generated. I wanted to have a double for-loop so I can tell the difference between each 'row' of cards. Right now I am not interested in the output yet, but for anyone who is, down below in the answers smarx shows a couple of nice ways to print the result.

Comment: Maybe you could include the desired output for your "small example". That would help. As far as I see it shouldn't be too hard for "5" but if it becomes too long an abbreviated expected output would be enough.

Comment: Allright, I will keep that in mind for any future questions. Thank you!

Comment: But please also [edit] this question including the output, just to make it useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j)
```

**EDIT**

Given the game you're trying to replicate, you may want something like this:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()

# Output:
# 0
# 0 1
# 0 1 2
# 0 1 2 3
```

**EDIT 2**

Or perhaps this:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(' ' * i, end='')
    for j in range(4 - i):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()

# Output:
# 0 1 2 3 
#  0 1 2 
#   0 1 
#    0
```

Comment: this is what I posted no?

Comment: It looks like it, yes.

Comment: I was looking for something like your first edit. Thanks!

Comment: Note that I just changed that first edit code... it should really be `range(4)` and `range(i + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You compute `rownum` only once, before entering the outer `for` loop -- but you actually need `rownum` to be different values during each iteration. That means you need to compute a new range *inside* the loop.

Do something like this:

```
for i in totalrow:
    for j in range(i):
        print(j)
```

This will loop in the pattern you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, I overcomplicated it for myself apparently

Comment: I have upvoted both, but I need 15 points for it to be visible.